# python flask app slows down after a long run due to memory usage. is there a way to free up memory in python?

Tags: python, flask

i am currently developing a python flask app that requires machine learnings to do some calculation on real-time data. the python flask im doing now had no issues on codes and all. when i first run the app, the calculation speeds of the python flask app was fast for the first hour. i left it until the next day and when i checked the data collection of the time, it seems to slow down a lot. suspected that could be using too much memory.

so my question to this is that is there a way that i could allocate the memories or to clear off the memory usage of the ram by Flask app so that it doesnt delay the machine learning prediction? and does freeing the memory used by the flask app can actually maintain the speed of calculation??

update: so i monitored the python app memory usage, and initially it started from 1GB and the next day it reach to the peak of 30GB. is this consider to be memory leak??

Comment: Could you please give a bit more infromation on, for example, how much RAM the system is using at start, what way it is increasing, etc?
My suspicion, if not the answer already given below, is that you accidentally keep reference too some temporary object, such that the garbage collector cannot clean anything up.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem to do with calling too many API's causing a memory leak. I recommend checking out this stack overflow page all about it: [Flask App Memory Leak caused by each API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49991234/flask-app-memory-leak-caused-by-each-api-call)

If those don't work I recommend manually garbage collecting your memory by using the gc package:

```
import gc

gc.collect()
```

Comment: so i have not apply this to my python yet because i wanna see the memory usage of my python app. so initally when i started it was 1gb on server, then the next day it slows down as it reach up to 30GB. does this consider as memory leak, and is it wise to use gc.collect() to dispose the garbage at this point??